# How can I resolve this error I'm getting in my movement script?

Tags: unity, c#

For my player controlling script, I have attempted to do it so the player can only jump two times, I've not had any errors in the script itself but when I save it and go back on Unity, the error I keep getting is this:

> error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `Collision.gameObject`

This is my code:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float power;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    int numberofJumps = 0;
    public int doubleJump = 2;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        numberofJumps = doubleJump;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.left * speed);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (numberofJumps > 0)
            {
                Jump();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * power, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        numberofJumps -= 1;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "ground") 
        {
            numberofJumps = doubleJump;
        }

    }
}
```

The error seems to be specifically regarding this line:

```csharp
if (Collision.gameObject.tag == "ground")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to make a static call on the `Collision` class. Try replacing this line

```
Collision.gameObject.tag == "ground"
```

With the reference to the object `col` passed in

```
col.gameObject.tag == "ground"
```

Comment: Man, thank you so much. I can't believe it was that simple.